# Message contract translation to SOAP message

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, serialization, soap

How .NET framework creates SOAP message from message contract? Which serializer class is used to serialize the message contract?

Comment: Why do you want to know? What would you like to accomplish?

Comment: @John Saunders: I wanted to see how the SOAP message will look like when message contract is serialized/formatted. After some digging, I have found the class that can actually help me achieve that without sending the message over the wire. `TypedMessageConverter` class has several `Create` static method overloads returning an instance of class inheriting from `TypedMessageConverter`. I can pass a message contract instance to one of its `ToMessage` method overloads and call `ToString` method on the returned `Message` to achieve what I really wanted. I will be posting the example some time today

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Deep below the cover, the SOAP message is mainly constructed using `SerializeReply` method of class implementing `System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.IDispatchMessageFormatter` interface. There are two internal  formatters using `XmlObjectSerializer` and `XmlSerializer` implementations to serialize message headers and body.

Luckily, there is another, public class that provides wanted functionality. The `TypedMessageConverter` internally creates dispatch message formatter in similar fashion to formatter set for a dispatch operation. It uses private `GetOperationFormatter` method in `Create` static method overloads in order to create instance of internal `System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlMessageConverter` class.

After creating the `TypedMessageConverter` implementation instance, one can pass message contract instance into `ToMessage` method. Finally, call to `ToString` method on `Message` instance returns expected SOAP message string.

```
TypedMessageConverter converter = TypedMessageConverter.Create(
    typeof( CustomMessage ),
    "http://schemas.cyclone.com/2011/03/services/Service/GetData",
    "http://schemas.cyclone.com/2011/03/data",
    new DataContractFormatAttribute() { Style = OperationFormatStyle.Rpc } );
CustomMessage body = new CustomMessage()
{
    // Setting of properties omitted
};
Message message = converter.ToMessage( body, MessageVersion.Soap12 );
string soapMessage = message.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

This will depend on your configuration. By default `basicHttpBinding` and `wsHttpBinding` use the [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) class. As far as the SOAP envelopes are concerned I don't know what classes are used and I am not sure if they would be public (I might be wrong on this).

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, it is not directly used by serializer. It creates internal structure of `Message` type which is then written based on `MessageVersion` and selected `Encoder`.

Internal structure is prepared by `TypedMessageConverter`. I think it is a class responsible of message contract processing. Unfortunately, it is abstract class with internal implementation.

Because of that, message contracts works with both `DataContractSerializer` and `XmlSerializer`.

Answer (score -1):

To answer the question "I wanted to see how the SOAP message will look like when message contract is serialized/formatted"

You can use a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) which lets you see whats going on over the wire. Here you can track the actual message xml being sent across.